# Redirect to mobile version while still retaining domain name

Tags: javascript, php, apache, redirect, server

I have a site, I need to use JavaScript or some other method to redirect users to the mobile version (which has files on a specific directory). I created a subdomain (`m.domain.com`) but then I realised I do not have a wildcard certificate for the `domain.com`. Is there a way to redirect to the mobile version (i.e. change the home directory to the mobile directory) without affecting the domain name?

i.e. if I visit site `domain.com` from desktop, it loads from `/var/www/html` but if I visit from mobile, it loads from `/var/www/html/mobile` while retaining `domain.com`. I'm on apache ubuntu running PHP so I don't mind if this redirection is server-side.

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Yes, you can have both codes from normal and mobile in same page, and check if the user is on mobile or not and just show that part to the user ! so u always use same domain !

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library to detect if the user is using mobile or desktop and then in your main folder :

```
/var/www/html
```

Add this index.php :

```
<?php

if(on mobile)
{
 include(mobile/index.php);
}
else
{
 // the code for desktop
}
```